# Where to put ads in a screen having both Tabbar Controller and Navigation Controller

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbar, iad

I have an iPhone application, which has both bottom Tabbar controller and Navigation Controller in the same screen. Where should I place the ads to appear relevant and not out of place.

I have seen a few applications like Fring, which place the ads just below the navbar. I was worried if this is a violation of your ad contract as the ad is more likely to be clicked by mistake when people are interacting with the navbar items. Please advice...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lots of apps have ads near control elements (e.g. check out "fat my face free"), so putting it just under the navbar should be ok. Besides, there isn't too much space on the phone anyway - it's not like you should stick it into the middle of the screen just to separate it from the navbar.

And it probably will work better if you put it between the tabbar and the view (i.e. close to the bottom of the screen).